# Cant Send Email When Using Dedicated Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am getting this Error ,

```
Send Email Failed.Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 
Unable to relay for myEmail@itaxsmart.com
```

Before this i was using godeady for databse and publish site .this code working Before,
Now i have  transfer  and published my `Database` and site on my `Dedicated server`  and i am Getting unable to Replay from server's IP Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** system.net.mail namespace is used for emailing.

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
 //Code for send Email
            MailMessage sendMailforSA = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpforSA = new SmtpClient();
            string subjectforSA = null;
            subjectforSA = "Thanks for apply";
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credforSA = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Superman@gmail.com", "password");
            sendMailforSA.To.Add(txtemailid.Value);
            MailAddress cc = new MailAddress("info@superman.com");
            sendMailforSA.CC.Add(cc);

 // sendMailforSA.CC("abcxxx@gmail.com");

     sendMailforSA.From = new MailAddress("Rajnikant@gmail.com");
            sendMailforSA.Subject = subjectforSA.ToString();
            sendMailforSA.Body =" Thank you.... your message you can use html tag for style effect";
            sendMailforSA.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtpforSA.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpforSA.Port = 25;
            smtpforSA.EnableSsl = false;
            smtpforSA.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpforSA.Credentials = credforSA;
            smtpforSA.Send(sendMailforSA);

}
```

http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-send-email-in-asp.html

Comment: what should i set on server side ?

Comment: have Tried this Code but i m not getting Email in Inbox I got message that mail sent succefully.

Comment: Send Email Failed.The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. j10sm9492356oej.10 –

Answer (score 0):

copy the following code.. its working for my gmail account

in web.config

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="youremail@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="youremail" password="xx" defaultCredentials="false"/>

  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

In code behind ( on button click)

```
Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
Dim smail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
smail.To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("emailtowhomyouwanttosend@yahoo.com "))
smail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("youremail@gmail.com", "Visit me")
smail.Subject = "hiii"
smail.IsBodyHtml = "true"
smail.Body = "HELLO THERE"
smtp.EnableSsl = True
smtp.Send(smail)
```

It will work for sure..

Comment: what should i change on server side meas IIS setting ?

Comment: no need to change iis setting but make sure your iis start and web config. <mailsettings> ok

Comment: Email :System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b8sm1062206anm.4 at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, String from) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) \

Comment: Send Email Failed.The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. j10sm9492356oej.10